# export and import to different tablespace

Tags: oracle, import, export, exp, imp

I am after doing an export from a tablespace and then importing it into a different tablespace. However i cannot use datapump as i want to do an export into my local pc and then import it from my local drive:

as it stands i am using the following commands:

```
exp user1/password@database1 file=C:\export\emp.dmp log=C:\export\emp.log tables=user1.table1:20-01-2016,user1.table1:21-01-2016

imp user2/password@database2 file=C:\export\emp.dmp log=C:\export\imp.log
```

however because its in different tablespaces i cannot see the table as it doesnt seem to be working

any ideas if this is possible with the normal exp and imp method?
if not any other ideas on how to do?

Comment: "it doesn't seem to be working" - what output do you get, and what does the log say? Have you created the table in the new tablespace before importing? What is user2's default tablespace and its quota? [And have you seen this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/original_import.htm#SUTIL1787)?

Comment: thank you i will look into that link, if i remenber correctly the error was to do with the tablespace. I will provide an update as soon as i am on my laptop